# How to count cells in a row while skipping specific columns?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Basically, I need to count non-blank cells in a row and I need to skip certain columns/cells in that row. I'm sure this is simple combination of functions but I can't seem to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=COUNTA( {I28:K28, M28, N28} )
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

If, e.g., you mean to count non-blank cells in row 1, excluding columns `E:F` and cell `H1`, use

```
=COUNTA(1:1)-COUNTA(E:F,H1)
```

The needed changes for other uses are obvious.